# Semantic versioning in Gitlab CI pipeline

Tags: gitlab, gitlab-ci, devops, gitlab-ci-runner, semantic-versioning

How to implement semantic versioning in Gitlab CI pipeline.I tried to few ways but it didn’t work. I tried writing githooks and versioning is generating as expected but I am not able to update the tag with latest version. I used below command to update,

git tag “$newVersion”

git push origin "$newVersion"
git tag -a -m "Update version to $VERSION" Version "$newVersion"

git push -uf origin main

but no use.
i want to implement semantic versioning in gitlab ci pipeline. for every pipeline run it should display the vesion as below,

1.0.0, 1.0.1, 1.0.2, 1.0.3 and so on

git tag “$newVersion”

git push origin "$newVersion"
git tag -a -m "Update version to $VERSION" Version "$newVersion"

git push -uf origin main

Comment: You need to set push credentials and then you need something like our code here - see lines 20-33 - https://gitlab.com/taleodor/sample-helm-cd/-/blob/master/.gitlab-ci.yml

Comment: Any sample code to achieve that...

Comment: Sample code is in the link in my previous comment; if you're looking for e2e instructions using our tool, check here - https://docs.relizahub.com/get-started/

Comment: Would https://about.gitlab.com/releases/2024/03/21/gitlab-16-10-released/#semantic-versioning-in-the-cicd-catalog be of interest?